# QGIS 3 interprets polylines as multipolylines?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

`ogrinfo -al` reports a file as `Geometry: Line String` and each feature as `LINESTRING`. But when loaded in QGIS 3, it is reported as `Line (MultiLineString)`. As far as I remember, QGIS 2 imported it as `LineString`. Is this an intentional change or a bug?

(By the way, is the command "Multipart to Single Parts" in QGIS 3?)

Comment: In what format your source data are?

Comment: It is a shapefile. I remember from QGIS 2 that I used geometry.asPolyline() but with the same data in QGIS 3 the function returned an empty set so I had to use geometry.asMultiPolyline() instead.